# Why override in the constructor cancel out modifications to the incoming value?

Tags: scala

I guess this has been discussed many times by now, but this is something I do not understand:

```
class A(val name: String) {   
  println("A ("+ name +")") 
}

class B(override val name: String) extends A(name = name + "1") {   
  println("B ("+ name +")") 
}

val b = new B("Olle") 
println(b.name)
```

This gives the output:

```
A (Olle1)
B (Olle)
Olle
```

Why is Scala designed this way? The output "Olle1" seems more natural to me ..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, `val name: String` translates into a private field on class `A`, a getter method, a constructor parameter *and* a constructor initialization.

When you do `override val name: String`, you are overriding the getter. You *can't* override the private field, because it is private, so it needs a new private field on class `B` as well.

Finally, constructor initialization -- first the private field `name` on `A` is set by `A`'s constructor, then the private field `name` on `B` is defined by *it's* constructor. Since we are talking about two constructors, `A`'s and `B`'s, their parameters are independent.

As [pedrofurla](https://stackoverflow.com/users/480674/pedrofurla) said, if you didn't really want to override `A`'s value, all you needed to do is not put `override val` before the constructor parameter.

Comment: I think this part of the Scala design isn't very intuitive. If I do not use the "override val" keywords I can get into very weird situations since I could use B's private "name" value by mistake when inside the B class.

Comment: @olle Yeah, I'd rather it simply disallowed it, only allowing `def` overrides for getter and setter, but `val` is considered a more strict contract than `def` -- a guarantee that the returned value won't ever change.

Answer (score 4):

Not using override gets the effect you want:

```
class A(val name: String) {   
  println("A ("+ name +")") 
}

class B(name: String) extends A(name = name + "1") {   
  println("B ("+ name +")") 
}

val b = new B("Olle") 
println(b.name)

scala> val b = new B("Olle")
A (Olle1)
B (Olle)
b: B = B@cc3e8

scala> println(b.name)
Olle1
```

Comment: Warning! This might seem like a good solution, but it is not. The reason is that this solution creates a private field name in class B, and this field might be confused with the public name-field in class A. Believe me, this strategy will result in bugs that are very hard to find.